# Loop Object inside array inside object inside array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop  Object inside array inside object inside array  and I am really confused!

here is my arr:

```
var arr = [
{
title: "Harry Potter",
categories: [
{
id: 39,
name: "Popular Books"
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Kids"
},
{
id: 79,
name: "All Books"
}
]
},


{
title: "Pride and Prejudice",
categories: [
{
id: 36,
name: "Classic Books"
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Woman"
},
{
id: 79,
name: "All Books"
}
]
}
]
```

How do I get the title of books that only have category name "Kids"?

Right now all I can think of is:

```
var find = function(arr){
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<arr[i].categories; j++){
      console.log(arr[i].categories[j].name)
    }
  }
}
```

Which is super dirty and does not work anyway.
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use filter to *filter* out those array elements with categories matching "Kids", then *map* their titles into a new array.

```
arr.filter( i => i.categories.some(j => j.name ==="Kids") ).map(k => k.title )
```

```js
var arr = [{
    title: "Harry Potter",
    categories: [{
        id: 39,
        name: "Popular Books"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Kids"
      },
      {
        id: 79,
        name: "All Books"
      }
    ]
  },


  {
    title: "Pride and Prejudice",
    categories: [{
        id: 36,
        name: "Classic Books"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Woman"
      },
      {
        id: 79,
        name: "All Books"
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(arr.filter(i => i.categories.some(j => j.name === "Kids")).map(k => k.title));
```

Comment: Yours is exactly same as mine. Didn't saw this answer.

Comment: Just a pointer, you are using 3 loops. `.filter`, `.some` and then `.map`. You can reduce iterations using `.reduce` + `.some`

Comment: If it helped you, consider accepting it as the answer.

Comment: definitely it helped, I accepted as the answer (did not even know I can do it))

Comment: Hi @dev8080: My requirement is almost same as this question. And i tried with your answer, too but am not getting the exact output. 
Can you please help me?
https://jsfiddle.net/jasie/4jhd7zrs/10/

Comment: hey @aananddham is https://jsfiddle.net/2o98qvfk/ what u want?

Answer (score 1):

have a try:

```
var find = function(arr, name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].categories.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i].categories[j].name === name) {
                return arr[i].categories[j];
            }
        }
    }
}

find(arr, 'Kids')
```